# Click the button then Datatrigger doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I'm stuck with some problems in my WPF code. for detail, I have a button and a hidden image. When the mouse moves over this button, the image will be visible and vice versa (there I used Datatrigger IsMouseOver), and when the button was clicked, if the image state was Hidden, show it and hide if it was shown. Initial, Datatrigger works fine but until I click to show the image, and click again to hide the image then Datatrigger does not work.

Dose anyone know why? - Thanks a lot!

- Here is the code in XML

  ```
     <DockPanel Style="{StaticResource 0005}">
           <Image x:Name="imgAr1" Source="/Image/Arrow.png" Style="{StaticResource 0006-1}"/>
           <Button x:Name="bntArrow1" 
                   Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=0003}" 
                   Click="bntArrow1_Click">
           </Button>
     </DockPanel>
  ```
- Here is styles for the image

  ```
     <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="0006">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"></Setter>
     </Style>
     <Style TargetType="Image" BasedOn="{StaticResource 0006}" x:Key="0006-1">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=bntArrow1, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true">
                 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
             </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  ```
- Here is button click event

  ```
    bool b = false;
    private void bntArrow1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (b)
        {
            imgAr1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            b = !b;
        }
        else
        {
            imgAr1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            b = !b;
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: Setting `imgAr1.Visibility` has higher precedence than the Style Setters. As soon as you set a "local value", the Style Setter in the DataTrigger will be ineffective.

Comment: I think the click should be `if(imgAr1.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden) { imgAr1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; } else { imgAr1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; }`. (By overriding the meta data as shown in duplicate link.)